# How to change "Activities" text on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview, top-bar

I want to know how can I change the "Activities" text to my own text for example "Task Manager", or is it possible if I can change it to an **image icon**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do both.

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Activities Configurator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) to achieve your goal. It lets you

> Configure the Activities Button and Top Panel. Select an icon. Change the text.

And provides many more customisations.

[image]
(screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

Comment: hi, i'm getting this error "you need to disable hot corner" in Ubuntu 18.04,can you suggest other extensions?

Comment: @CloudSky It's not an error per se. Activities Configurator requires hot corner option to be on. But it also provides an option to turn it off from the extension settings.  So you can first enable "Activities Overview Hot Corner" option in GNOME Tweaks > Top Bar, then install Activities Configurator  extension, and finally disable hot corner from the extension's settings window as in the screenshot in the answer.